# Echoing multiple check boxes

Tags: php, forms, checkbox, cpanel, survey

I am trying to write some code for a collection form for a fake dating form. I'd like the form, or the 'end' screen repeat back what the user has put in for their information.

I have text fields and radio buttons that I was able to repeat back to the user but for some reason when I do the checkbox portion of it, it is only repeating back the last answer I gave. (I know this isn't the correct code, but I am currently not knowledgeable about other solutions)

For example, this is what I have coded now, when I select 'men' and 'women'.

I only receive the echo "You are attracted to women" is there anyway I can get multiple answers from the checkboxes repeated back to me?

Form Code:

```
                if($_POST['pg'] == 'M') {
                    echo "You are attracted to men"."<br>";
                } else if ($_POST['pg'] == 'F') {
                    echo "You are attracted to women"."<br>";
                } else {
                    echo "You are attracted to gender neutral people"."<br>";
                }
```

Initial Survey code:

```
<p>What Gender/s are you attracted to?
                <input type="checkbox" name="pg" value="M"> Male
                <input type="checkbox" name="pg" value="F"> Female
                <input type="checkbox" name="pg" value="GN"> Gender Neutral
                </p>
```

What I would like to see is:

You are 'attracted to men and women' for this example. So it would repeat what the survey filler has entered in.

Comment: You haven't shared your HTML form. I see there is already a helpful answer about checkbox inputs. I recommend sharing your form and clarifying your question. You asked, "is there anyway I can get multiple repeated back to me?" Multiple what? We need to see your form.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @drolex thank you for letting me know, I fixed it up a bit to make it clearer!

Answer (score 0):

In case of radiobutton - you can have only one value (the same input name)
In case of checkbox - you can have as many options selected as possible.
So you either use

```
<input type="checkbox" value="test1" name="pg[]">
<input type="checkbox" value="test2" name="pg[]">
<input type="checkbox" value="test3" name="pg[]">
```

Or you have to use different names for each checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" name="pg_test1">
<input type="checkbox" name="pg_test2">
<input type="checkbox" name="pg_test3">
```